# ldap Invalid Credentials While Authenticating User(NodeJs)

Tags: node.js, active-directory, ldap, gssapi, ldapjs

There are two Active Directory (LDAP Servers). Following are the users which belongs to their servers respectively.

```
     Server         user                         password

1-   abc.pk           user_abc@abc.pk              ********

2-   xyz.com.pk       user_xyz@xyz.com.pk          ********
```

I am authenticating the user in NodeJS with library (ActiveDirectory). Below is my code where I am authenticating **user_xyz@xyz.com.pk** from its respective server.

```
       const ActiveDirectory = require('activedirectory');
       var ad = new ActiveDirectory({
           "url": "ldap://xyz.com.pk",
           "baseDN": "DC=xyz,DC=com,DC=pk"
});
                    ad.authenticate(username, password, function(err, auth) {
                        console.log('auth function called with username: '+username);
                        if (err) {
                            console.log('auth function called and with following err  '+JSON.stringify(err));
                            return;
                        }           
                        if (auth) {
                          console.log('Authenticated from Active directory!');
                      });
```

it works fine. Same works fine if I authenticate **user_abc@abc.pk** from server 1 by updating the url and baseDN.

```
       var ad = new ActiveDirectory({
           "url": "ldap://abc.pk",
           "baseDN": "DC=abc,DC=pk"
});
```

Server **abc.pk** has Trust Relations with Server **xyz.com.pk**. Means I have to authenticate the user **user_abc@abc.pk** from the Server **xyz.com.pk** . using the following configurations.

```
      var ad = new ActiveDirectory({
               "url": "ldap://xyz.com.pk",
               "baseDN": "DC=xyz,DC=com,DC=pk"
    });
```

but now facing the error of invalid credentials. This is the exact error I am facing  **{"lde_message":"80090308: LdapErr: DSID-0C090453, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 52e, v3839\u0000","lde_dn":null}**

If I authenticate the **user_abc@abc.pk** from **xyz.com.pk** Server with  **Active Directory Explorer** it works fine.

[Active Directory Explorer image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1asi5.png)

It would be a great help if someone could give me a solution.
Thanks

Comment: In addition I came to know one thing the **Active Directory Explorer** is authenticating with **GSS-API** mechanism instead of simple authentication.  I have searched a lot but couldn't find library in NodeJS to implement that mechanism. Will much appreciate if someone could suggest me solution.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem by checking the following 2 things:
1.-The configuration must be separated in the baseDN part:

```
var config = {
url: 'ldap://aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd',
baseDN: 'DC=aaa,DC=bbb,DC=ccc,DC=ddd'
```

};

2.-It seems the problem is not from code [https://community.arubanetworks.com/community-home/digestviewer/viewthread?MID=40296#:~:text=%22AcceptSecurityContext%20error%2C%20data%2052e%22,instead%20of%20just%20the%20username](https://community.arubanetworks.com/community-home/digestviewer/viewthread?MID=40296#:%7E:text=%22AcceptSecurityContext%20error%2C%20data%2052e%22,instead%20of%20just%20the%20username).

According to the post, sometimes the domain name server may be required for authentication. It would be necessary to verify if it works with "**username**" or "**username@aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd**" or "**aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd\username**" depending on how the user is registered.

I hope my experience can be of use. Cheers